# Need a help on fetching value based on a key from a config file

Tags: python, regex, linux, awk, sed

I have a file containing similar data

```
[xxx]

name = xxx
address = bangalore

[yyy]

name = yyy
address = sjc
```

Please help me getting a regex that I can fetch the address/name value based on xxx or yyy (xxx or yyy and address or name is the input)

Comment: This is easier done with a programming language eg `PHP` or `Python`, is this a possibility?

Comment: thanks !! please suggest python , I can try out in the environment and update you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with `awk` if your file is just like that (i.e., the `name` is the same as the section and it is before the `address`):

```
$ awk -v nm='yyy' -F ' *= *' '$1=="name" && $2==nm{infi=1; next}
                              $1=="address" && infi {print $2; infi=0}' file
sjc
```

Or, better still you can get the section and then fetch the key, value as they occur and print them and then exit:

```
$ awk -v sec='yyy' -v key='address' '
                    BEGIN{
                          FS=" *= *"
                          pat=sprintf("^\\[%s\\]", sec)} 
                    $0 ~ pat {secin=$1; next}
                    NF==2 && $1==key && secin ~ pat {print $2; exit}' file
sjc
```

If you want to gather all sections with their key/value pairs, you can do (with `gawk`):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=" *= *"}
       /^\[[^\]]+\]/ && NF==1 {sec=$1; next} 
       NF==2 {d[sec][$1]=$2}
       END{ for (k in d){
                printf "%s: ",k
                for (v in d[k])
                    printf "\t%s = %s\n", v, d[k][v]
                        }
           }' file
[xxx]:  address = bangalore
        name = xxx
[yyy]:  address = sjc
        name = yyy
```

---

Config or .ini files can have quoting like csv, so it is best to use a full config file parser. You can use [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/Config-Simple-4.59/Simple.pm) or [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) that have robust libraries for parsing .ini or config type files.

Python example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/tmp/file")
```

Then you can grab the sections, the items in each section, or a specific items in a specific section:

```
>>> config.sections()
['xxx', 'yyy']
>>> config.items("yyy")
[('name', 'yyy'), ('address', 'sjc')]
>>> config.get("xxx", "address")
'bangalore'
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex to the rescue!
This approach splits the entries into single elements and parses the key-value-pairs afterwards. In the end, you can simply ask your resulting dictionary for ie. `values['xxx']`.
See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/vvAcMQ).

```
import re

string = """
[xxx]

name = xxx
address = bangalore

[yyy]

name = yyy
address = sjc
"""

rx_item = re.compile(r'''
    ^\[(?P<name>[^][]*)\]
    .*?
    (?=^\[[^][]*\]$|\Z)
    ''', re.X | re.M | re.DOTALL)

rx_value = re.compile(r'^(?P<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?P<value>.+)$', re.MULTILINE)

values = {item.group('name'): {
            m.group('key'): m.group('value') 
            for m in rx_value.finditer(item.group(0))}
            for item in rx_item.finditer(string)
        }

print(values)
# {'xxx': {'name': 'xxx', 'address': 'bangalore'}, 'yyy': {'name': 'yyy', 'address': 'sjc'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're trying to search for the value inside the square brackets or the value of the "name" tag but here's a solution to one possible interpretation of your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *= *" }
!NF   { next }
NF<2  { prt(); k=$0 }
      { map[$1] = $2 }
END   { prt() }
function prt() { if (k=="["key"]") print map[tag]; delete map }

$ awk -v key='yyy' -v tag='address' -f tst.awk file
sjc

$ awk -v key='xxx' -v tag='address' -f tst.awk file
bangalore

$ awk -v key='xxx' -v tag='name' -f tst.awk file
xxx
```